# Can't Boot, video drivers or x-server problem?

Tags: boot, xorg, grub2

I was uninstalling some programs that I installed to try and get my iPod touch working with Ubuntu (I gave up on that) when ubuntu just crashed. Now after I choose ubuntu in GRUB, it gives me a screen that says "Ubuntu is running in low-graphics mode: your screen, graphics card, and input device settings could not be detected correctly. You will need to configure these yourself"

It was working just fine before I started to uninstall those programs. I think that I might have uninstalled something necessary to the system. If I click OK on the screen, it gives me options to reconfigure, troubleshoot, exit to console, or restart X. But no matter what I choose I still can't boot into ubuntu - I get stuck looking at the splash screen which stalls forever.

I was receiving support from one of my mate's and he was doing something with the LiveCD, and now the message doesn't pop up any more, I just get stuck at a never ending splash screen.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What graphicals card do you have ? Do you have any idea on what your mate did ?

Comment: I have no idea what he was up to, he was just messing around with xserver and such. I have an ATI Radeon X1200

Comment: It seems he he has removed the X server in order to reinstall - but had problems installing it again. I'm just going to opt for a clean install of Ubuntu instead of trying to fix. :P I had messed around with it too much that it was cluttered anyway.

Answer (score 1):

A work around for that sort of mess would be to switch away from the graphical console to a command line terminal (via Ctrl-Alt-F1), log in, then run:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Which should pull in all the packages the system needs for the basic desktop. This might not work — it all depends on what was done to get the system into the mess it's in — but it should produce some indication of what dependency problems you have if it fails.

Comment: try to sudo apt-get purge ubuntu-desktop
then
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop